# am I losing data when I am sharding my existent collection?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I had a collection with millions of objects in it, in just one server. I setup a config server and 2 shard nodes, being one of them the one that have that collection docs.
After I added the collection to be shard, everything looked fine. However something weird is happening , at the time that mongod is sharding that collection if I keep asking the size of the collection: `db.activity_items.count()` the number is decreasing. Why? am I losing any data somewhere?

This is some console output, just to illustrate the problem:

```
mongos> db.activity_items.count()
19107620
mongos> db.activity_items.count()
19107223
mongos> db.activity_items.count()
19106939
mongos> db.activity_items.count()
19106922
mongos> db.activity_items.count()
19027118
```

**EDIT**

if I run `db.activity_items.stats();` http://pastebin.com/85RqZmQM . It shows that the first shard node is decreasing the counter and the second shard node is not increasing its counter. which makes me think that my data is getting into a limbo .?.

**EDIT 2**

I stopped the balancer. and it stopped to lose data, however my old data didnt came back..

```
mongos> db.activity_items.count()
15736936
```

**EDIT 3**

I filled a bug about it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6696

Answer (score 0):

First let me say that I don't think you are losing data here.  It is far more likely that the issue lies with how the count() command is working in the sharded environment.  There have been bugs with the opposite behavior for example:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645

I think what is happening here is that the count is only actually executing correctly on the original shard and not returning (or returning zero) on the new shard.  What happens if you connect directly to the shard primaries and run the count there?

Also, run sh.status() so you can track the migrations.

As an experiment to see if this is temporary and caused by the migrations in-flight, try disabling the balancer temporarily:

```
// connect to mongos
> use config
> db.settings.update( { _id: "balancer" }, { $set : { stopped: true } } , true );
```

Once the in-flight migrations finish, try the counts again, see if they make sense.  Since you added a new shard both of them will be adding/removing documents constantly.  Until they are balanced and the migrations stop it will be difficult to say what the direct cause of the count deviations is, but this will tell you early if they will look sane again once the balancing is done.

EDIT: Per the comments - would be great to get your version and OS to see if this is reproducible and if so, file a bug to get it fixed.

Comment: added a couple of steps that will let you figure out if this is due to the ongoing balancing

Comment: ok. i just stopped the balance, it is still decreasing because i guess the in-flight migration is still happening. how can I check the in-flight migration status?

Comment: there are a couple of ways, but the easiest is the logs of the primaries - chunk migrations are logged in there.

Comment: what version (and OS) are you using? - I haven't seen this behavior before - would like to try to reproduce, see if this is a bug.  I'd also be curious to find out if the counts from the individual shards agree with the count from mongos

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and Mongo v2.0.4

Comment: I also tried to reproduce the error in localhost with 10k docs. but it didnt happend. also i tried this morning again with more docs this time. 100M and I am still losing docs.. if i connect to shard2 and do a coount in there.. the number is not 0, however it doest get increased . and in shard1 it gets lower and lower...

Comment: I can't find an obvious bug that matches, but my final suggestion would be to test with the 2.2.0-rc0 release candidate that is available to see if this persists in 2.2 and if so, then open a bug at http://jira.mongodb.org - like I said I would suspect a bug in count rather than actual data loss here - I have seen many successful implementations on larger data sets without any data loss.

Comment: talking about version. i just realize that i was running 2.0.4 in the primary shard and 2.0.6 in the secondary one.. this was probably causing the error.. i am trying to clean all my data.. and will start again using 2.0.6 in both. will let u know how it goes. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6696 - I believe this issue "works as designed"